# Paypal Android SDK for Non-US developers

Tags: android, paypal

I'm a Non-US developer building a Android app that will also run outside US.

I've searched for a while about when will the Android SDK be available outside US but couldn't find anything. I'm looking for a way of integrating Paypal payments with my app (using the Paypal Android SDK) and I'm afraid this availability outside US will take to much to be efective. Is there any official release date for this service outside US?

I know I can use MPL but I don't want to spend time with such technology that is being replaced by a newer one. Also, it probably wont offer the same UE as the official SDK does (starting an external activity).

What happens if I integrate my app with the current state of the SDK and publish it on the web?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did I get a "-1" in the question? Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Down voting is one of the dark sides of SO. Dare to ask about that on Meta and you will know what down voting means :-( Just get used to those trolls around there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh from PayPal here. There is no official date, but this is a high priority for us.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any way I can get news about this subject? I mean, a forum or thread that has news about it?

Comment: You might watch https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/7. It is not exactly the same, but they're related.

Comment: Actually, the proper link (to Android SDK is this one) https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/2 but thanks anyway